# Dynamically enable and disable DIV via MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic

Last night I was trying to figure out how I can how I can dynamically enable and disable `span#txtCaptchaDiv` on my contact form at the very bottom, above the submit button.

So I added a new field to MySQL, called `captcha` where I wanted to `1` to show and `0` to hide

So if I add `1` to field `captcha` the following code will show on my `form.php`

```
 <label for="code">Write code below > <span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="color:#F00"></span><!-- this is where the script will place the generated code --> 
  <input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" /></label><!-- this is where the script will place a copy of the code for validation: this is a hidden field -->
  <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" size="30" />
```

If I add `0` to field `captcha` the captcha area will be blank on my `form.php`.

Can you guy help me out please?

**here is my index.php code I currently have:**

```
<?php

require_once("/config/database.php");
$con = mysql_connect($config["db_server"],$config["db_user"],$config["db_pass"]);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email FORM</title>
</head>

<body>


<div style="width: 550px; text-align: center;">
<span style="filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:.6; padding-left: 10px;"><br />


<?php 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM formrelated") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 Print " ".$info['welcomemsg'] . ""; 
 ?>

 </span></div>


<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
<table width="454" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="123">Name</td>
    <td width="325">
      <input name="name" type="text" />
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="21">Address</td>
    <td><input name="adress" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="21">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="address2" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="21">Email</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="21">Tel</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--- captcha code here--->

<center>
<table width="454" height="122" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="reCAPbg.png">
  <tr>
    <td height="73" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><label for="code"><span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="color:#333; font-size:18px;"></span><!-- this is where the script will place the generated code --> 
      <input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" /></label></td>
    <td width="136" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="145"> type the code here:</td>
    <td width="173" height="47" align="center"><input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" size="20" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</center>
<!--- captcha code ends here--->

<input name="Submit" type="button" value="submit" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
//Generates the captcha function    
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';       
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';  
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';  
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';  

    var code = a + b + c + d + e;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;  
</script>




<script type="text/javascript">
function checkform(theform){
    var why = "";

    if(theform.txtInput.value == ""){
        why += "- Security code should not be empty.\n";
    }
    if(theform.txtInput.value != ""){
        if(ValidCaptcha(theform.txtInput.value) == false){
            why += "- Security code did not match.\n";
        }
    }
    if(why != ""){
        alert(why);
        return false;
    }
}

// Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function   
function ValidCaptcha(){
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
    if (str1 == str2){
        return true;    
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

// Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
function removeSpaces(string){
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? Or want us to write it for you?

Comment: I added my entire index.php thanks for the edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you... enjoy!

```
    <?PHP

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT captcha FROM formrelated WHERE id = '1'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $captchathis = $row['captcha'];

         if ($captchathis == "1") {
           echo "YOUR HTML CODE HERE";
        }
        else {
           echo "BLANK";
        }
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
<?PHP
    if($mysqlResult['captcha'] === 1)
    {
        echo $myHtml;
    }
?>
```

Where `$mysqlResult` is an *array* with the result from the query, `$mysqlResult['captcha']`is the value of the row `captcha` from your query and `$myHtml` is that HTML code you just showed on your answer.

Good luck! ;)

Reffer to

http://php.net/manual/en/

**EDIT:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php ( `Array` type on the manual )

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php ( `If` control structure on the manual )

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php ( `MySQL` *native* functions. **deprecated**. Preffer `MySQLi` )

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php ( `MySQLi` *extension* )

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php ( `PDO` *native* php *class* )

Comment: any other advice on getting $myHtml to dispaly the   captcha code?

Comment: Basically what you have to do is an `if` to check if it attends some _condition_ (in this case, check if `captcha` is equals to `1`).
So, anything that does the following works:  
    <?PHP
      if($captcha === 1)
      {
        //Do Something
      }
    ?>

Comment: sorry Im really new to this, my field captcha in under table  formrelated, how can I pull that data to with echo?

Comment: What is stored in formrelated ?

Comment: On formrelated table the field captcha is there with value 1

Comment: What else ?
If it is only that row, i would suggest you to simply save it in the PHP file as `$captcha = true;` then check with `if($captcha === true){ echo $captchaInput; }`

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to explain the basic construct of IF logic.

Suppose i have some condition i want to meet to do something; in this case, the following logic

```
SHOW my form with the basic inputs
IF condition 'captcha = 1' is met, SHOW input2 (captcha)
SHOW rest of the HTML
```

it would be like this in PHP

```
<?PHP
  echo $myFormWithBasicInputs;
  if($captcha === 1)
  {
    echo $input2;
  }
  echo $restOfHTML;
?>
```

In your case, `$myFormWithBasicInput` and `$restOfHTML` is already outputed as HTML. All you want to do is inject an PHP code in it to check if some condition is matched. It will be like this

```
<html>
  <!-- MY FORM WITH BASIC INPUTS -->
  <?PHP
    $captcha = $mySQLresult['captchaRow'];
    if($captcha === 1)
    {
  ?>
    <!-- CAPTCHA INPUT HERE -->
  <?PHP
    }
  ?>
  <!-- REST OF HTML -->
</html>
```

be aware that this is an workaround with example code.

Comment: I added that code with the captcha code in place mySQl, and I added 1 value to Captcha. It didnt returned anything?

Comment: The _gray_ HTML in my code are comments. Put your HTML code and test ;). BTW, be aware that this is just example code, you shouldn't use it after all

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?PHP
    $mysql_query = "SELECT captcha FROM formrelated";
    $captcha = $mySQLresult['captchaRow'];
    if($captcha === 1)
    {
  ?>

<!--- CODE---->
<table width="454" height="122" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="reCAPbg.png">
  <tr>
    <td height="73" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><label for="code"><span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="color:#333; font-size:18px;"></span><!-- this is where the script will place the generated code --> 
      <input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" /></label></td>
    <td width="136" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="145"> type the code here:</td>
    <td width="173" height="47" align="center"><input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" size="20" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>


  <?PHP
    }
  ?>
  <!-- REST OF HTML -->
```

Comment: It's almost exactly like this. But you forgot to _execute_ the `$mysql_query` and save the _output_ into the `$mySQLresult` var. BTW, this isn't _at all_ an answer :P